# How to get data from response.json and pass that to component?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am really new to React and Redux. I have created this form

```
// node modules
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';

// custom modules
import apiRequest from '../../redux/modules/apiRequests';

const renderField = ({ type, label, input, meta: { touched, error }}) => (
    <div className="input-row">
      <br />
      <label>{label}</label>
      <br />
      <input {...input} type={ type }/>
      { touched && error &&
       <span className="error">{ error }</span>}
    </div>
  )

class LocationForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      address: '',
      city: '',
      state: ''
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = event => {
   this.setState({
     [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   });
 }

  submit = ({ address='', city='', state=''}) => {
    // console.log(`state: ${this.state.address}`)
    let error = {};
    let isError = false;

    if (address.trim() === '') {
      error.address = 'Required';
      isError = true;
    }

    if (city.trim() === '') {
      error.city = 'Required';
      isError = true;
    }

    if (state.trim() === '') {
      error.state = 'Required';
      isError = true;
    }

    if (isError) {
      throw new SubmissionError(error);
    } else {
      console.log(this.props)
      apiRequest.post(`/search`, this.state)
      console.log(this.props)
      this.setState({ address: '', city: '', state: ''})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit(this.submit) }>
        <Field name="address" label='Address: ' component={renderField} type="text" onChange={this.handleOnChange} />
        <Field name="city" label='City: ' component={renderField} type="text" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
        <Field name="state" label='State: ' component={renderField} type="text" onChange={this.handleOnChange}/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

LocationForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'location'
})(LocationForm)

export default LocationForm;
```

and this is my post method in apiRequest.js

```
post(url, body) {
  return fetch(API_URL + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }).then(response => console.log((response.json())))
  }
```

I do see the response that I need from the server when I do console.log.

But I just don't understand how do I take that response/ store it in a variable/ store as a current state so, that I can pass it on to location component to show it on a screen. I do see the result as ...

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"[[PromiseValue]]: Objecthospitals: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]pharmacies: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]restaurants: (20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]schools: (20)[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]trains: (2) [{…}, {…}]__proto__: Object
```

Thanks you for any suggestion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response.json returns a Promise. I suggest you to look at [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you don't know much about them.

What you need to do is returning the result of response.json() and then read the data from response.

```
post(url, body) {
  return fetch(API_URL + url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }).then(response => (response.json())).then((json) => {
    console.log('Response JSON: ', json);
  })
}
```